# JQuery - How to rotate an element forwards and backwards one time?

Tags: jquery, animation, rotation

Maybe the answer is pretty simple, but every solution I've found has either an infinite rotation, or one rotation. What I'd like to do is rotate an element forwards, then backwards to the original position, triggered by a button press.

It's part of a small game I'm making, here it is on JSFiddle. It rotates upwards, but I'd like the div to rotate back to the original position:

```
$(function () {
    $('#button').click(function() {
        swingArm();
    });

});

function swingArm() {
    $rollingPin = $('#rolling-pin');
    $({ deg: 0 }).animate({ deg: 50 }, {
        duration: 400,
        step: function (now) {

            $rollingPin.css({
                transform: 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)'
            });
        }
    });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cw4bj3tf/

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

With this method you are simply using a CSS3 animation and jQuery's toggle class to trigger it. It's a much more simple method that allows you to specify the key-frames. I set it to default of just a swing but you can easily make it raise the pin and swing it like he is upset or something. Hope this helps!

Edit: I changed it to use and remove from style. This now works every time on each click event. You can specify a time in ms in the or function or it will default to 500ms. Enjoy!

Edit: Just for fun right click the button and you can see the shake i was referring to!

```js
$('#button').click(function() {
  swingArm();
});

$('#button').contextmenu(function() {
  shakeArm( 1000 );
});

function moveToby() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $(".toby").stop(true, true).animate({
        left: 450
      }, 1000,
      function() {
        $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
          left: 0
        }, 1000);
      });
  }, 2000);
}

function swingArm( swingTime ) {
  if(!swingTime) swingTime = 500;
  $("#rolling-pin").css('animation', swingTime+'ms swing-pin');
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#rolling-pin").removeAttr('style');
  },swingTime+1);
}

function shakeArm( swingTime ) {
  if(!swingTime) swingTime = 500;
  $("#rolling-pin").css('animation', swingTime+'ms shake-pin');
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#rolling-pin").removeAttr('style');
  },swingTime+1);
}
```

```css
#game-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
  height: 660px;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/QxOVkCJ.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}

#rolling-pin {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 480px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/zcZTO3z.png');
  background-size: cover;
}

#button {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/v3sQNLD.png');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.toby {
  position: absolute;
  height: 239px;
  width: 80px;
  bottom: 157px;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/ym3YyVW.png');
  background-size: cover;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

@keyframes swing-pin {
 0% {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 50% {
  transform: rotate(50deg);
 }
 100%{
  transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
}

@keyframes shake-pin {
 0% {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 30% {
  transform: rotate(50deg);
 }
    40% {
      transform: rotate(25deg);
    }
    50% {
      transform: rotate(50deg);
    }
    60% {
      transform: rotate(25deg);
    }
    70% {
      transform: rotate(50deg);
    }
 100%{
  transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="game-container">
    <div id="rolling-pin"></div>
    <div class="toby"></div>
    <div class="toby hidden"></div>
    <div id="button"></div>
    <div id="youWin">Continue</div>
    <div id="youLose">Continue</div>
  </div>
</body>
```